How to mask the area outer Image 1 to see Image 2?
I am trying to make a hillshade with Image 1 and Image 2. I am looking for a method to mask area around
Image 1
so that in the final render the Image 2 will be visible

I am trying to create a better hillshade map like this

In my mind creating a separate material would help to colour the mountain part only so that the image would look better. Also, I have mask available

There could be a better way around. I'm attaching the blend file here https://we.tl/t-Q9iLmrBg12

You might try running it through the compositor by bringing it in as an Image and trying the Dilate/Erode node.
